# Differing Web API ModelState error responses depending on data type

Tags: sql-server, database, asp.net-web-api, database-design, model

We're using `.NET Web API` with `SQL Server`. It seems like the default error responses I get from the API differ depending on the data type of the column. On the front end, we have a table that users fill out which fills the aformentioned database table. If I submit a record with blank values for all of these required fields, this is what the API returns in the console (in the 'Network' --> 'Response' tab):

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "myTable": [
      "Required property 'columnInt1' not found in JSON. Path '', line x, position xxx.",
      "Required property 'columnInt2' not found in JSON. Path '', line x, position xxx.",
      "Required property 'columnInt3' not found in JSON. Path '', line x, position xxx.",
      "Required property 'columnDecimal' not found in JSON. Path '', line x, position xxx."
    ],
    "myTable.columnString1": [
      "The columnString1 field is required."
    ],
            ],
    "myTable.columnString2": [
      "The columnString2 field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

Note the different error responses depending on data type. If I change one of the varchar columns to int or decimal datatype, its error response changes to match the message that the rest of int/decimal columns have `("Required property 'columnInt1' not found in JSON. Path '', line x, position xxx")`.

I'd prefer all the errors have the response that the two varchar columns have (`"The stringColumn1 field is required."`, etc). **Is there a way to modify this default behavior, and why is this a thing?**

Below is an example of our table design:

```
Column Name:       Data Type:           Allow Nulls:
columnInt1              int                   no
columnInt2              int                   no
columnInt3              int                   no
columnDecimal           decimal(5, 2)         no
stringColumn1           varchar(4)            no
stringColumn2           varchar(5)            no
```

Our API model for this table looks like:

```
    [Required]
    public int columnInt1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int columnInt2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int columnInt3 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Precision(4,2)]
    public decimal columnDecimal { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string columnString1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string columnString2 { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a way to move the int and decimal error messages to be more like those of the strings. AKA, I can make `columnInt1` have the ModelState response `The columnInt1 field is required`.

It requires combining the optional parameter `?` with the `[Required]` attribute, which seems kind of janky to me. Can anyone tell me what negative effects this could possibly cause, if any? Or just how bad practice this truly is? Or - perhaps its not a big deal? Seems to work for my purposes.

Here's how my model looks with the fix:

```
[Required]
public int? columnInt1 { get; set; }    // the ? seems contradictory to [Required], but fixes my issue

[Required]
public int? columnInt2 { get; set; }

[Required]
public int? columnInt3 { get; set; }

[Required]
[Precision(4,2)]
public decimal? columnDecimal { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(4)]
public string columnString1 { get; set; }

[Required]
[StringLength(5)]
public string columnString2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Note - I ended up solving this issue without having to manipulate the modelState - we left it as, undid the changes to the model above and got the error messages another (completely unrelated and not helpful for this topic) way. But would still like to know more about the peculiar behavior above if Jon Skeet happens to pop in...